# NET 7 - Identity Server - Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Method 'get_ServerSideSessions'

Tags: asp.net-core, identity, .net-7.0, duende-identity-server

Getting the following exception in

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapRazorPages(); }):
```

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.Method 'get_ServerSideSessions' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.ApiAuthorizationDbContext`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

After updating the nuget package Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework to version 6.2.0. and Duende.IdentityServer.Storage to 6.2.0. Reverting both package back to 6.0.4 resolves this error , seems like there is an incompatibility introduced. If anyone has a fix so I can upgrade this package is appreciated.

Comment: Check out [this github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44990). It seems there are some workarounds there.

Comment: I have checked that but I'm stuck like MichelJansson. After update all, when mapping endpoints (endpoints.MapRazorPages();).
It looks like some reflection code is finding the original ApiAuthorizationDbContext with the older interface even though it's not used anywhere.

Comment: If you try to use what `neozhu` said in the link `Guru Stron` offered,will it be solved?

Comment: Nop, if I remove the package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer I have an error in these lines: services.AddIdentityServer()... and services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt()